# MDT LiteTouchPE Windows 8.1 deployment very slow

Tags: pxe-boot, wds, windows-8.1, mdt

I'm deploying Windows 8.1 via network boot using MDT on an external hard drive connected to computer to create a Windows To Go drive.

But the step in my task sequence "Install Operating System" takes a lot of time (+ 45 min).

I tried to do the same deployment on the internal drive and the same step takes only 5 min.

I tried to add USB 3 drivers in LiteTouchPE because the external hard drive is USB 3. But it is still very slow, I don't know if the drivers where correctly installed.

Or is it something else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend that you look over [Deploy Windows To Go in Your Organization](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/jj721578) and [Create Windows-To-Go drives in a simple Factory mode](http://blogs.technet.com/b/deploymentguys/archive/2013/02/27/create-windows-to-go-drives-in-a-simple-factory-mode.aspx). Pushing an image to a USB drive with MDT does not make a Windows To Go workspace, you need to use the Windows To Go Creator Wizard or use PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

I tested with a usb3 thumb drive with a SSD controller and it is faster than on the external hard drive it seams it is a material limitation.